# How to add a checkbox dynamically for all rows and columns while page onload with Datatables?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, datatables

I need to add checkboxes in all rows and column header while onload of datatable.

Here is the HTML code

```
<body>
    <c:if test="${not empty table}">
  ${table}
</c:if>

</body>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#sheet_0').DataTable();

        var container = $('#sheet_0');
        var rowSize = $('table#sheet_0 tr').length
        alert(rowSize);

        for (var r = 0; r < rowSize; r++) {
            $('<input />', {
                type : 'checkbox',
                id : 'cb' + id,
                value : name
            }).appendTo('tr');
        }

    });     
</script>
```

I have done like above checkboxes are not loaded.
The table is loaded by reading an Xlsx file and load into HTML

Using spring I have set the table content in model attribute and view in html.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id="sheet_0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
          <tr>
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_1" colspan="3">Seguros Generales</td><td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_1" colspan="3">Seguros de Personas</td><td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_1" rowspan="2">Total general</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="td_0_2">Modalidad</td><td class="td_0_2">Ramo</td><td class="td_0_2">LBC-G</td><td class="td_0_2">CRI-G</td><td class="td_0_2">ILL-G</td><td class="td_0_2">ALI-G</td><td class="td_0_3">BIS-G</td><td class="td_0_3">FOR-G</td><td class="td_0_3">LAT-G</td><td class="td_0_2">TOT. SG</td><td class="td_0_3">BUP-P</td><td class="td_0_2">LVI-P</td><td class="td_0_2">LBC-P</td><td class="td_0_3">PRO-P</td><td class="td_0_3">NAL-P</td><td class="td_0_3">ALI-P</td><td class="td_0_3">CRDI-P</td><td class="td_0_2">TOT. SP</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="td_0_2">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_2">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_2">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_2">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_2">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_2">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_3">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_3">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_3">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_2">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_3">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_2">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_2">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_3">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_3">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_3">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_3">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_2">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_2">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="td_0_2">Seguros Generales</td><td class="td_0_2">Incendio</td><td class="td_0_3">0.0</td><td class="td_0_4">-</td><td class="td_0_4">-</td><td class="td_0_4">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_3">0.0</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_4">-</td><td class="td_0_4">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_2">-</td><td class="td_0_2">0.0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="td_0_2">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_2">Robo</td><td class="td_0_4">-</td><td class="td_0_4">-</td><td class="td_0_4">-</td><td class="td_0_4">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_2">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_4">-</td><td class="td_0_4">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_2">-</td><td class="td_0_2">-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="td_0_2">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_2">Transportes</td><td class="td_0_4">-</td><td class="td_0_4">-</td><td class="td_0_4">-</td><td class="td_0_4">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_2">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_4">-</td><td class="td_0_4">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_3">-</td><td class="td_0_2">-</td><td class="td_0_2">-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Please, reformat your source code, so the horizontal scrollbar will disappear.

Comment: Where do Id come from? its missing from your code

Comment: Actually there are so many td's inside a single tr, So its coming like that

Comment: Id comes from the Java class where i convert xlsx to html, like below
Element table = htmlDocumentFacade.createTable();
  int sIndex = sheet.getWorkbook().getSheetIndex(sheet);
  String sId = "sheet_".concat(String.valueOf(sIndex));
  table.setAttribute("id", sId);
  table.setAttribute("border", "1");
  table.setAttribute("cellpadding", "2");
  table.setAttribute("cellspacing", "0");
  table.setAttribute("style", "border-collapse: collapse;");

Comment: @ShankaraNethranS.N As I understand your code: you append a checkbox to a tr element, not a td element. so no wonder, why you don't see any checkboxes.

Comment: @reporter Yes Thats the issue, I dono whether my code is correct, but i assume it as, Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @ShankaraNethranS.N A checkbox as children of a tr element is invalid HTML syntax.

Comment: @reporter Yeah understood, Since i am not familiar with Jquery datatables and HTML, I am unable to get the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According my try at jsfiddle try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sheet_0').DataTable();
    var id = 0;

    //Look for the table and tbody to find all table rows ('tr')
   $('table#sheet_0 tbody tr').each(function()
   {
     //Take each founded table row to look for columns ('td')
     $(this).find('td:first').each(function()
     {
        //Take each founded column and append a checkbox
        $('<input />', {
            type : 'checkbox',
            id : 'cb' + id,
            value : name
        }).appendTo($(this));
        id++;
     });
   });
});
```

This code example adds a checkbox to first columns.

And the above example for an ondinary html table, without th tags:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#sheet_0').DataTable();
    var id = 0;
    var tableRows =  $('table#sheet_0 tr');

    for (i = 0; i < $(tableRows).length; i++)
    {
      //Skip first table row
      if (i > 0)
      {
        //Take each founded table row to look for columns ('td')
        $(tableRows).get(id).find('td:first').each(function()
        {
            //Take each founded column and append a checkbox
            $('<input />', {
               type : 'checkbox',
               id : 'cb' + id,
               value : name
            }).appendTo($(this));
            id++;
        });
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Checkboxes are not appended

Comment: Yes reporter Checkboxes has been appended now but I need it to be the done in an First TD of every TR's and should be converted to datatable

Comment: @ShankaraNethranS.N See my edits. Important!: There are some strange errors in your html so the plugin itself does not create a datatable of your expectations. Please read the manual carefully. I solved this issue by using the example table from website. Hint: You have to add `thead` and `tbody`to your table. And there are some other mistakes in your code.

Comment: Since i dont need any thead because I am converting whole Excel file to Html table, [dynamically occurs]. So As of now I need checkboxes in a new row of the table instead of table headers accordingly the size of each td into the tr

Comment: @ShankaraNethranS.N The plugin need it to create a datable. Have a look at instructions.

Comment: @ShankaraNethranS.N see my update for an odinary html table. So you got two versions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149588/discussion-between-shankara-nethran-s-n-and-reporter).

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you need to add a callback to your datatable initialization:

```
var options = [];
options.drawCallback = function(stgs){
   //you can loop all table with foreach loop if you won't loop replace $(this)
$(this).find("td:first-child").html("<input type='checkbox'  value='sth' />");
};
$("#table_id").DataTable(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) plug-in for jQuery DataTables.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   'columnDefs': [
      {
         'targets': 0,
         'checkboxes': true
      }
   ],
   'order': [[1, 'asc']]
});
```

See [Checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) plug-in page and [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/snqw56dw/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Actually after reading the xlsx file, I will get a HTML, in that I am selecting table alone and convert to datatable on pageLoad, After doing the above mentioned things still am not able to load checkboxes in columns of datatable, What may be the issue, correct me if I am wrong